# Property 'intersect' is missing in type 'import("cesium").BoundingSphere' but required in type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cesiumjs

I have been trying to implement Cesium in ReactJs application where various factories are shown in the cesium viewer and polygon grids are drawn on the factory co-ordinates. Everything is working fine but one thing is making confusion. I am trying to set dynamic camera height relative to my factory, That means The bigger the factory the higher the camera so that the whole factory is covered by the Camera on the first Load.

For this purpose, I was trying to use the `<CameraFlyToBoundingSphere>` component from Resium (React component of Cesium).

My Code is something like this bellow:

```js
const bound = new BoundingSphere(Cartesian3.fromDegrees(140, 35.7, 0), 0);

<Viewer>
  <CameraFlyToBoundingSphere
    boundingSphere={bound}
    offset={new HeadingPitchRange(0, Math.toRadians(-30), 80000)}
    duration={3}
  />

  <Entity key={index}>
    <PolygonGraphics
      hierarchy={positionArrayPoly}
      height={height}
      material={color}
      show={true}
      outline={selected}
      outlineColor={Color.WHITE}
      outlineWidth={10}
    />
  </Entity>
</Viewer>;
```

The whole code is obviously under a `Functional Component`. Just didn't wanna make it looks complicated as there are tons of other codes. SO here is the issue I am facing. This code sends me an error.

```
Property 'intersect' is missing in type 'import("cesium").Bounding Sphere' but required in type
```

By the way, I am using type Script from my project. Hope to have some suggestions from someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. The `const bound` needed to be changed a bit.

Defined a function name `flyToLatLng`

```
const flyToLatLng = (viewer: any, lat: number, lng: number) => {
    const bounds = BoundingSphere.fromPoints([
        Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lng, lat),
    ]);

    viewer.camera.flyToBoundingSphere(bounds, {
        duration: CAMERA_DURATION,
        offset: AREA_HEADING,
    });
};
```

Changed the viewer code a bit like Bellow:

```
<Viewer>
  <CameraCustom
    cRef={viewerRef}
    lat={cameraPosition.lat}
    long={cameraPosition.long}
  />

  <Entity key={index}>
    <PolygonGraphics
      hierarchy={positionArrayPoly}
      height={height}
      material={color}
      show={true}
      outline={selected}
      outlineColor={Color.WHITE}
      outlineWidth={10}
    />
  </Entity>
</Viewer>
```

Finally added the  component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { flyToLatLng } from '../lib/camera';

interface Props {
    cRef: any;
    lat: number;
    long: number;
}

const CameraCustom: React.FC<Props> = ({ cRef, lat, long }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        flyToLatLng(cRef.current.cesiumElement, lat, long);
    });

    return <></>;
};

export default CameraCustom;
```

Hope it will be helpful for some one so added the solution here